# Organize TSNE data into grid

Tags: graphs, tsne

I have some data reduced by TSNE into a 2D representation, which shows clear spatial features.

[image: 2D data organized by TSNE]

However, I'd like to format this into a grid – not just snapping data to the nearest grid square but spreading everything out to fill up a grid, preserving (as much as possible) the existing spatial relationships.

So far, I've only found [this article](https://www.computer.org/csdl/trans/tg/2012/05/ttg2012050797-abs.html) which might close to what I need? This process might already have a name and I'm just one step from an easy Google solution, but at the moment I'm stuck!

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @Emre – see my answer below for images of the result. I wanted to do something similar to http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/cnnembed/ but for text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to be a few options, but I found [rasterfairy](https://github.com/Quasimondo/RasterFairy) which is very easy to install and use. Has the added bonus of being able to fit to a rectangular grid, but also circular and other arbitrary shapes.

A very nice IronPython notebook example: https://github.com/Quasimondo/RasterFairy/blob/master/examples/Raster%20Fairy%20Demo%201.ipynb

And some example results:

[image: tsne before gridding]

[image: gridded tsne]

Comment: Looks like it dosen't have python 3 support. What a shame

Comment: My lab made a fork of this library with identical API and python 3 support. Just `pip install yale-dhlab-facenet`. https://pypi.org/project/yale-dhlab-facenet/